# Highlight a Telerik RadGrid row based on error

Tags: ajax, vb.net, telerik, radgrid

I would like to highlight a row from my RadGrid base on a logic row error (not database related).
I'm using Telerik Ajax .net RadGrid With VB.NET

```
 If ok > 2000 Then

Dim errorRowOrderNumber = ok / 1000

'Get the RadGrid row error index

 myErrorRow.Drawing.Color.Red
 myErrorRow.Drawing.Color.White


 End If
```

Comment: Check this [Link](http://www.telerik.com/forums/gridview-validation-and-error-marking-coloring) 
Jack's post has some nice info on a similar problem it should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this if you can identify the error condition on item data bound event:

```
Protected Sub grid_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridItemEventArgs)
        Try    

            If TypeOf e.Item Is GridDataItem Then

                Dim dataRow = TryCast(e.Item, GridDataItem) 

              ' Replace with validation logic
              If True Then
                dataRow.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Gray
                dataRow.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.White
                dataRow.ToolTip = "Some information about this error."
              End If

            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
           ' handle exception
        End Try
End Sub
```

In any other grid command event you can get a reference to the same `GridDataItem` object.

If you can't use a grid event try looking into client-side options.

Comment: The error it's a a result of a logical test not database related. I edit my question to be more specific, sorry for that